# XRDP on Ubuntu 20.04 server multiple issues

Tags: gnome, 20.04, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

I just built a new server and installed Ubuntu 20.04 server on it.  Actually twice now.  I've followed multiple guides but cannot get XRDP to work correctly.  Best I have done so far is 1 connection from windows which seem to time out after a bit and never allows login again.  Also if I log out and try to connect again it fails.  I want a setup similar to my 16.04 desktop machines.  On those I use gnome locally and xfce4 when connecting from remote.

So far the best result I've got is on a clean install with no options selected.  Did the sudo apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.  Then installed xrdp followed by xfce4.  Then echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession This lets me do the one connection per reboot of the server but even that takes a few tries before it actually connects.  I've tried opening the port on firewall but no difference.  I've tried adding my user to some group that I can't even remember now and no change there.  Tried with ssl and adding to that group as well.  Nothing.  More I try the worse it gets.

I've also tried using my startwm.sh file from 16.04 and that gave me the one login to xfce4 with gnome installed but then seems to totally kill xrdp on remote session end.

No being logged in or out locally does not seem to have any affect. I've read you need to be logged out to use xrdp but on 16.04 I can be logged in locally and with multiple users on 5910, 5911, etc.

Speaking of 5910, 5911 does changing port to ask5910 in xrdp.ini still work or is it something else now.

Additional issue is installing gnome causes it to not work at all and unless I select either xfce4 or gnome from the list on each local login my keyboard and mouse quit working with the default ubuntu  desktop that gets installed along with gnome and becomes the default GUI.

None of this should be this hard.  Just trying to get a working local and remote GUI.

Comment: You do know 16.04 is EOL in April this year.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, installing xrdp is quite straightforward.  If you have Ubuntu 20.04 Server and that you have installed the Gnome Desktop Interface, you can use the xrdp-installer script that ease the installation and post configuration actions for xRDP

**Step 1 - Download the script**

```
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xrdp-installer-1.2.2.zip
```

**Step 2 - Extract content**

```
unzip xrdp-installer-1.2.2.zip
```

**Step 3 - Mark the file as executable**

```
chmod +x  ~/Downloads/xrdp-installer-1.2.2.sh
```

**Step 4 - Perform the installation**

```
 ./xrdp-installer-1.2.2.sh
```

You can pass some parameters to the script to customize your installation process
You can find more information at this location (https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15978)

xRDP version shipping with Ubuntu 18.04 does not allow a user to connect to the console session.

xRDP version shipping with Ubuntu 16.04 is an old version (0.6.1) using vnc technology which can help you reconnecting to your session (some configuration needed)

Hope this help
Till next time

Comment: Doesn't work.  Same issues as if I installed it manually.  Either get Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons.......... or An authentication error has occurred The function requested is not supported.  The second error I received after getting the first one a few times and trying to connect again.